# How to format the input "123456789" to fax/123456789@faxabc.com using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, asp-classic, vbscript

User inputs **1234567890** and then need to format that to **fax/123456789@faxabc.com**. Tried the following regular expression but not working:

```
fax/{\d+}/@fax.com
fax\//{\d+}/@faxabc.com
[fax\//{\d+}/@faxabc.com]
```

The closest one is `fax/{\d+}/@fax.com`, will get **fax123456789@faxabc.com**. However, need the "/" after the word fax.

Comment: Javascript: `var str= "fax/"+inputNumber+"@faxabc.com";`

Comment: Er, "javascript"/"asp"/"vbscript" ... pick one? And what on earth do regular expressions have to do with this? Just build the output string with concatenation...

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do here… Why are regular expressions necessary? Isn't string concatenation sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are trying to match it in a string so:

```
function formatFaxNo(s) {
  var re = /(\D)(\d+)(\D)/;
  return s.replace(re, '$1' + 'fax/'+'$2'+'@faxabc.com' + '$3');
}

// Here is a fax/123456789@faxabc.com number.
formatFaxNo('Here is a 123456789 number.'); 

// Fax to here: fax/123456789@faxabc.com.
formatFaxNo('Fax to here: 123456789.');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called string manipulation/concatenation, not regex:

```
    var input = 123456789; //or whatever user inputs
    var output = "fax/" + input + "@abc.com" ;
```

Anything wrong with that?